# Eclipse STS - Git Bitbucket

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

My Commit and Push from my STS Eclipse to Bitbucket worked fine the last year. I don't change anything there but today I get the following error:

[image: My Error]

Does anyone why?
If I make a **pull** I geht the following exception:

[image: valid]

Actually I dont know what to do, I have not changed anything concerning git in the last half year.

**[EDIT]**

[image: Error]

I have installed this Eclipse Bundles:

[image]

I think this is the problem:

> The POM for org.crashub:crash.shell:jar:1.3.1 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

**[EDIT2]**
I have installed the new version of STS (3.7.2) and Iam also getting the same Exception:

> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: invalid advertisement of 
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:223)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
>       at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.components.RefSpecPage$3.run(RefSpecPage.java:254)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.PackProtocolException: invalid advertisement of 
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$HttpObjectDB.invalidAdvertisement(TransportHttp.java:746)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp$HttpObjectDB.readAdvertisedImpl(TransportHttp.java:712)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.newDumbConnection(TransportHttp.java:328)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:306)
>       at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:202)
>       ... 4 more

With Git Bash it still works fine. Does anyone have any idea how I can sole this?

Comment: Looks like bitbucket changed something

Comment: Yes, it looks to me too but I don't know what to do now. I also can not find any hints to this exception message :-(

Comment: We did not change anything (I'm a Bitbucket dev). But considering some of your output shows an HTML doctype string, are you sure you've got the right URL? Mind sharing that here?

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for the response, with Git BASH it works fine. I guess it has something to do with the Eclipse STS GIT plugin. Currently my workout is to do a commit locally and then push with GIT BASH. The strange thing is that I did not do anything at STS and yesterday it worked fine - today I am getting this error.